# Using alpha version on composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I have the following workflow in my [open source](https://github.com/devqaly/sdk-laravel) library:

1. Have a branch `next` where all branches should branch out from
2. User works on feature `X` and opens a pull request to branch `next`
3. We merge the feature into `next` and releases a new version tagged `vx.x.x-alpha`
4. Now, the consumer tries to upgrade the package with: `composer require devqaly/devqaly-laravel "0.1.3-alpha"`

Whenever the consumer tries to update the package he gets the following error:

```
➜  devqaly-example-app-api git:(master) ✗ composer require devqaly/devqaly-laravel "0.1.3-alpha"

./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update devqaly/devqaly-laravel
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires devqaly/devqaly-laravel 0.1.3-alpha -> satisfiable by devqaly/devqaly-laravel[v0.1.3-alpha].
    - devqaly/devqaly-laravel v0.1.3-alpha requires devqaly/devqaly-php 0.1.2-alpha -> found devqaly/devqaly-php[v0.1.2-alpha] but it does not match your minimum-stability.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

## What the consumer has tried

The consumer tried to update the `package.json` file manually to specify the new version AND delete the `vendor` folder. Then, running `composer install` but still gets the same error.

## Questions

1. Is the workflow correct? I understand there is not a final answer here but just trying to understand if this could be improved
2. Why is the consumer getting the error?

## EDIT 1

Here's my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "devqaly/devqaly-laravel": "v0.1.3-alpha",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.24",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I have also removed `"minimum-stability"` and `"prefer-stable"` but the error still persists.

Comment: What is the `minimum-stability` property set to in composer.json?  Pretty sure edits to package.json won't do anything for composer.

Comment: @imabug I have edited the question with my composer.json

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @imabug I have set my `"minimum-stability"` in my `composer.json` to `alpha` and it is working now.

```
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
```

Here are the [docs for it](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability)